# Правильное отображение

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем добрый день!

У меня есть данная функция которая отображает класс .butons при нажатии на .facttext и обратно.
Вопрос как сделать так чтобы.
 1. При нажатии на .facttext выключался .buttons и сам .facttext, вместо .facttext появлялся к примеру .newfacttext.
 2. Если нажать на .newfacttext включался .buttons и .facttext, а .newfacttext выключался?
(и так циклично)

Заранее спасибо!

```
$(function () { $('.facttext').click(function (e) { var $buttons = $('.buttons');

if ($buttons.css('display') != 'block') {
    $buttons.show();

    var firstClick = false;
    $(".facttext").bind('click.myEvent', function (e) {
        if (!firstClick && $(e.target).closest('.buttons').length == 0) {
            $buttons.hide();
            $(".facttext").unbind('click.myEvent');
        }
        firstClick = false;
    });
}

e.preventDefault();
```

});
});

Comment: Какая у вас структура html?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: @DOsS, вы меня не поняли. Как эти объекты расположены относительно друг друга? Какие из них родительские, какие дочерние или родственные? Вот так?:

    <div class="buttons">
       <div class="facttext"></div>
       <div class="newfacttext"></div>
    </div>

Comment: <div class="buttons"></div>

<div style="display:block; color:#ffffff; padding:5px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:12px; z-index: 999;"> 
        <img src="i/pic1.png" class="facttext">
 </div>
 
 <div style="display:none; color:#ffffff; padding:5px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:12px; z-index: 999;"> 
        <img src="i/pic2.png" class="newfacttext"> 
 </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js "></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $buttons = $('.buttons');                 
            $(this).on('click','.facttext',function(){
                $buttons.toggle(); 
                $(this).parent().hide();
                $('.newfacttext').parent().show();

            });
            $(this).on('click','.newfacttext',function(){
                $buttons.toggle(); 
                 $(this).parent().hide();
                $('.facttext').parent().show();

            });
        });
     </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="buttons">button</div>

    <div style="display:block; color:#ffffff; padding:5px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:12px; z-index: 999;"> 
        <img src="i/pic1.png" class="facttext" /> 
    </div>
    <div style="display:none; color:#ffffff; padding:5px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:12px; z-index: 999;"> 
        <img src="i/pic2.png" class="newfacttext" />  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Извините можно чуть развернутый ответ.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dOsS/thyZC/ 

Думаю так будет понятнее.

 При нажатии на .facttext выключался .buttons и сам .facttext, вместо .facttext появлялся к примеру .newfacttext. 2. Если нажать на .newfacttext включался .buttons и .facttext, а .newfacttext выключался?
(и так циклично)

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Чрезмерно благодарен!! Все работает!!!

Answer (score 0):

Я только не могу понять, каким там боком ко всему относиться блок buttons, но можно [таким образом сделать](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/H8AeH/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dOsS/thyZC/ 

Думаю так будет понятнее.

 При нажатии на .facttext выключался .buttons и сам .facttext, вместо .facttext появлялся к примеру .newfacttext. 2. Если нажать на .newfacttext включался .buttons и .facttext, а .newfacttext выключался?
(и так циклично)